# Macro to Limit %

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel spreadsheet which has multiple tabs and cells filled with % values. There are some cells which read 20%, 30%, 40% etc and the format of these cells are 'percentage'. There is a sum cell which sums up all these percentages to equal 100%. I am trying to write a simple macro/rule which would constantly read the sum cell and throw out an alert if it does not equal 100%. I am not sure how to proceed.

I am trying to use Data Validation to do this instead of any coding as what I really want is for the users to be unable to change the values of cells if the total changes from 100. Data Validation still is not working. It always seems to throw errors. Anyone have any thoughts on this ? I have selected the range of numbers and in data validation I am choosing Custom where I am saying = Sum(C5:C10)=100. This is always throwing an error even when the total is 100. Any thoughts ?

Comment: You need to specify the RANGE that you want to ensure sums to 100%.

Comment: Its 5 cells, C1:C5. and C6 is SUM(C1:C5). I want to set up a rule which would constantly check if C6 is 100% and if not, pop up an alert.

Comment: How do you want the alert to pop up? through a message box?

Comment: Yes. Through a message box.

Comment: Have you considered Conditional Formatting for cell C6?

Comment: Why not just use conditional formatting instead of VBA Code? Is that an option for you.

Comment: I am trying to use Data Validation to do this instead of any coding as what I really want is for the users to be unable to change the values of cells if the total changes from 100. Data Validation still is not working. It always seems to throw errors. Anyone have any thoughts on this ?

Comment: @Amritha Can you please send me your workbook. I can make the data validation work for you. My email address is:  daniel.ferry@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your question correctly you'll be able to do this without any code.

For example, your percentage cells are on Sheet3, Sheet4 and Sheet5 in the ranges B2:B6.

On Sheet6 you can use the formula `=SUM(Sheet3:Sheet5!$B$2:$B$6)`
*NB:  This is a 3D formula and works providing Sheet4 is between Sheet3 & Sheet5 in tab order.*

You can then use conditional formatting on the total - **Format only cells that contain** - **Cell Value is greater than 1**.
Then format it as something obvious (I generally use bold yellow text with a red background).

Ok, as reply to your comment, add this code to the worksheet code module which will run every time the sheet calculates:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    If Cells(6, 3) > 1 Then
        MsgBox "Total is too high"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I wanted the alert to pop up as a message box if any of the inputs are changed. All the inputs are on the same sheet.

Comment: In that case use the code I've added at the bottom of my reply.  Edit:  Saying that, you want it to check if it's not 100%.  Using <>1 will throw the error on every input until the total equals 100% which is probably not what you want - as @Vincent said in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a UDF to replace the SUM function:

```
Function SumAndAlert(rng As Range) As Variant
    SumAndAlert = Application.Sum(rng)
    If Application.CountBlank(rng) = 0 And SumAndAlert <> 1 Then MsgBox "not 100%"
End Function
```

but I think it might be a little annoying to have message boxes poping out while entering data.

Comment: Yes, not while entering. If either of the input % have been changed, I wanted a msgbox to pop and say total does not add to 100.

Comment: I edited the solution to not send message if some cells of the range are empty.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use the Worksheet_Calculate event procedure because doing so would cause much too frequent evaluation of the MsgBox condition.

Try to keep that to an absolute minimum like so:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Count = 1 Then
        If Target.Column = 3 Then
            If Target.Row < 6 Then
                If Val(Me.[c6]) > 1 Then
                    MsgBox "Greater than 100%"
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @Amritha Were you able to get this going?